# XPages runtime error: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: lotus/domino/RichTextItem.convertToHTML(Ljava/util/Vector;)Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

My code is meant to extract the contents of a RichText item as HTML, but I get a runtime error.

```
Document doc = getExpression().getRefDoc();
Session session = doc.getParentDatabase().getParent();
boolean flag = session.isConvertMime();
session.setConvertMime(false);
Item item = doc.getFirstItem(itemName);
Vector options = new Vector();
String html = "";
if (item.getType() == Item.RICHTEXT)
    html = ((RichTextItem) item).convertToHTML(options);  // error
session.setConvertMime(flag);
return Utils.toVector(html);
```

As far as I know, the convertToHTML method isn't defined as abstract.

Can someone please explain why I get the error, and what I can do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could likely happen if you run the code on a server that doesn't have that method. I think it was added in V10 or thereabouts, so, if you use, say, Designer V11 and run on Domino V9, you'll get that error.

Comment: Alas... Domino Designer Release 11.0.1FP2, Server build number Release 11.0.1

Comment: Are you using an older build of ODA? That could do the same.

Comment: No ODA involved, just commons-io-2.6.jar and de.leonso.xfl.3.18.02.jar (we're using extended formula language quite a lot).

Comment: Hi Jesse, you're right, it did have to do with a mismatch. The XFL jar I've got isn't compiled with the latest version, and somehow it needed some method that didn't have the right specifications. Thanks for your help!